# Swift and Xcode 6.0 Sizing Not Displaying Correcty

Tags: xcode, image, swift, size, constraints

My problem is that when I add constraints to images, they do not size correctly. So it looks really different when you try it on different devices.

Iphone 6 Image: http://sta.sh/027d5awmyin3
Iphone 4s Image: http://sta.sh/0245jhtb5hls

Has anyone else experienced this problem? This is really bugging me and I would really appreciate a thorough answer to this. I am a little new to Swift and Xcode so dumb it up for me :)

Comment: Your debugger console throws out constraint errors. Take a deep look at them to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: It says "2014-10-07 07:04:47.097 Lagniappe[16395:460225] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property"

Comment: Read further - the interesting part comes right after this text. Each constraint conflict is listed there to give you hints what's going wrong.

Comment: Check here lol: http://sta.sh/065uqolvmy5

Comment: The width contstraint (234) for a UIButton cannot be satisfied at runtime.

Comment: Why can't it be satisfied?

Answer (score 0):

That means that you have multiple constraints set on the button and at least on of these constraints cannot be satisfied at runtime.

Example: When you set constraints for the left distance, right distance **AND** the width of the button. In that case, remove the width constraint because the width of the button is automatically determined be the left and right distances.

Comment: Ok. So only use one type of constraint. Which one do you think will provide the best look on each build of the iPhone?

Comment: This is my problem: My images shrink but the buttons don't shrink, so I get a weird size on different builds of the iPhone. Images: http://sta.sh/020j4z6b8k4a | http://sta.sh/0nihmrwkmh0

Comment: For me it looks perfect! So what's the problem?

Comment: The pictures are waaaaay smaller on the iPhone 4s than on the iPhone 6. It's just a little frustrating .